# Reload shipping methods in checkout page

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I notice that everytime I change Country, State/Province in checkout page, it reloads the Shipping Methods section. Depending on the country/state, it would be 1 or 2 shipping methods.

If I choose UK, there is only 1 shipping method

[image]

If I choose US; there is 2 shipping methods
[image]

I wonder how it can listen to the input changes and which function in checkout module updates shipping methods. Could you guys show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below file is resposible for this shipping estimation functionality.

**/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php**

Here has the method like:

1. **estimateByAddress**
2. **estimateByExtendedAddress**
3. **estimateByAddressId**
4. **getEstimatedRates**
5. **getShippingMethods**